# Where you can declare variables in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am reading C++ FAQs. In Chapter 16, Using Static it says that:

> "a const static data member is declared in the class and is normally
>   defined (and initialized) in a source file, such as a .cpp file. But
>   in some cases it can be initialized in the class body proper."

and then goes on to mention where integral and non-integral types can be declared (although I think this changed for integrals in C++11).

**My question is, does the above only apply to const static data members and not non-const static data members?**

I am starting to get really confused and not seeing why there are these restrictions? Are there these rules for volatile, mutable and other keyword variables? How can someone learn this easily (besides programming it 24/7)?

Comment: In C++03, only in the class if it's a static, const, integral type.

Comment: To learn more, you'll have to read the documentation *carefully*. There's often a lot of subtlety in how things are defined, but if you follow the examples given you should get a general sense of how it works. It's not necessary to known every single thing about C++ to use it effectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ 2011 didn't change anything with respect to *declaring* variables! However, you can *initialize* all member variables in the body of a class definition. When constructing an object, the value declared in the class definition is the value used by default. If the member initializer list mentions the members, the initializer list takes precedence, however.

Static data members generally need to be defined. However, `static` and `const` members may get away with a declaration and an initialization in the class body: If the member isn't bound to a reference or its address being taken, the declaration suffices and you don't need to provide a definition. However, if you take the address it still needs to be defined.

Here are a few examples of how defaults for the member initialization can be set up:

```
class foo
{
private:
    int i{5};
    int j = 6;
    std::vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    std::vector<int> w = std::vector<int>(2, 10);
    std::vector<int> z = decltype(z)(2, 10);

    // ...
};
```

Note, that using parenthesis doesn't work. Thus, it may be necessary to use one of the last two forms above.

Comment: Is a good rule to define AND initialise at the same time, because the value will be "reachable" before any instances of the class are created?

Comment: Also, by "body of a class definition" do you mean what is found in the header file, the specification?

Comment: @user997112: The initialization is done when it is the member's turn to be constructed - not earlier, not later. ... and I'm pretty sure that the *class definition* is the, well, class definition. It specifies the class's name, base classes, members, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The general reasoning is that it must be defined in a source file if it needs storage. If it's a static const integer, it doesn't need storage - the compiler can just substitute a literal integer everywhere you use the variable. If it's non-static, it's a member variable that needs storage in each object. If it's non-const, you need a place to keep the value when it's updated.

Comment: Are you saying whether the variable is const or not is irrelevant?

Comment: @user997112, yes it matters if it's const or not. Sorry if I'm not being clear, but I think my answer indicates that.

Comment: Ah ok, I get you- a static const value is obviously ever going to change, so at compile time we know it's value throughout and hence the different declaration allowances.